# Wordpress: Can I delete all database tables that the prefix does not match with the $table_prefix in wp-config.php

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am very new to WordPress and database, almost a year of building websites with WordPress, I have used many plugins to change the database table prefix for security reason, and I have also changed to many hosting providers which all of them helped me migrate the website files and database.

I have just noticed that my database size is almost 2GB which is too large and it is impossible with this very big size. So I logged in to the phpMyadmin and found that there are many database tables that the prefix does not match with the $table_prefix in wp-config.php.

I am not sure whether it is normal to have the tables that the prefix does not match with the $table_prefix in wp-config.php ? are those tables just a duplicating unused table? Should I delete all of them?

If this is not normal, possibly the plugin that helped me change the prefix or the hosting provider who helped me migrating the site might cause this problem.

Comment: if you are sure they are not being used then there shouldn't be a problem. Does your db have cached data? you can sort by table size in phpmyadmin which will definitely help you locate the problematic table(s).

Comment: Some plugins don't use the prefix when creating database tables (which is not a recommended practice but it happens anyways) so you really should do some research before deleting any of these tables to be 100% they're not being used by some plugin/script, as Mech said above.